# No output with a return error of 1 while using pointers to char in c++

Tags: c++

I have thoroughly searched for an answer to no avail. I have been using Starting out with C++ Gaddis textbook as reference. I know there is a simple answer to this problem, but I'm having trouble figuring it out. Here's my code:

```
class Employee
{
    private:
    char *name;
    int idNumber;
    char *department;
    char *position;
    void initName(const char *n)
{
    name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
    strcpy(name, n);
}
void initDepartment(char *d)
{
    department = new char[strlen(d) + 1];
    strcpy(department, d);
}

void initPosition(char *p)
{
    position = new char[strlen(p) + 1];
    strcpy(position, p);
}

public:

Employee()
{
    strcpy(name, "");
    idNumber = 0;
    strcpy(department, "");
    strcpy(position, "");

}
Employee(char *nam, int num, char *dep, char *posit)
{
    initName(nam);
    idNumber = num;
    initDepartment(dep);
    initPosition(posit);
}

Employee(const char *nam, int num)
{
    initName(nam);
    idNumber = num;
    strcpy(department, "");
    strcpy(position, "");   
}

~Employee()
{
    delete [] name;
    delete [] department;
    delete [] position;
}

void setName(char *n)
{
    name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
    strcpy(name, n);
}

void setIdNumber(int num)
{
    idNumber = num;
}

void setDepartment(char *d)
{
    department = new char[strlen(d) + 1];
    strcpy(department, d);
}

void setPosition(char *p)
{
    position = new char[strlen(p) + 1];
    strcpy(position, p);
}

const char * getName() const
{
    return name;
}

int getIdNumber() const
{
    return idNumber;
}

const char * getDepartment() const 
{
    return department;
}

const char * getPosition() const 
{
    return position;
}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
const int SIZE = 50;
const char name[SIZE] = "Mark Jones";
Employee employee(name, 3452);
const char *ptr = NULL;

ptr = employee.getName();

cout << ptr << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem, man? What error are you getting? At which line? BTW, that `strcpy(department, "");` and similar lines look extremely weird, you'd better use `memset` to clear the contents of `department`

Comment: With a pointer, by default (ignore that it could be initialized with garbage), doesn't point to anything. Something has to be instantiated which the pointer can point to - so can you assign a value to something that has not been instantiated? Look carefully at the strings and how you handle them in the constructor..

Comment: @Nim, a C++ pointer always points somewhere. It may point to zero or it may point to something your program is not permitted to access, but it always points somewhere.

Comment: @ForceBru when i run the program there is no output and returns a exit error of 1. I want to output the name "Mark Jones".

Comment: @nicomp, splitting hairs! ;) That should have read, "point to anything useful"!

Comment: @Nim - "Splitting hairs" is a stereotype for SO!  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default constructor you copy empty string to the trash pointer:

```
Employee()
// name and all other members are not initialized
{
    strcpy(name, ""); // << copy to unallocated memory
    idNumber = 0;
    strcpy(department, ""); // << and here
    strcpy(position, ""); // << and here
}
```

The proper default constructor would be:

```
Employee()
: name(nullptr) // Initialize all members here
, idNumber(0)
, department(nullptr)
, position(nullptr)
{
    // Initialize c-strings
    initName("");
    initDepartment("");
    initPosition("");
}
```

Do not forget to use `const` all along. And similarly other constructors:

```
Employee(const char* nam, int num, const char* dep, const char* posit)
: name(nullptr) // << Initialize all members here
, idNumber(num) // << Initialize number with proper value
, department(nullptr)
, position(nullptr)
{
    initName(nam);
    initDepartment(dep);
    initPosition(posit);
}

Employee(const char* nam, int num)
: name(nullptr) // Initialize all members here
, idNumber(num) // << Initialize number with proper value
, department(nullptr)
, position(nullptr)
{
    initName(nam);
    initDepartment("");
    initPosition("");   
}
```

Proper functions' parameters:

```
void initName(const char *n)
{
    name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
    strcpy(name, n);
}
void initDepartment(const char *d)
{
    department = new char[strlen(d) + 1];
    strcpy(department, d);
}

void initPosition(const char *p)
{
    position = new char[strlen(p) + 1];
    strcpy(position, p);
}
```

And don't forget to clear memory in setters (otherwise it is a memleak):

```
void setName(const char *n)
{
    delete[] name;
    name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
    strcpy(name, n);
}

void setDepartment(const char *d)
{
    delete[] department;
    department = new char[strlen(d) + 1];
    strcpy(department, d);
}

void setPosition(char *p)
{
    delete[] position;
    position = new char[strlen(p) + 1];
    strcpy(position, p);
}
```

This should fix all your runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

Rather use the member functions in the constructor. The pointers are not initialized when the constructor starts, but the member functions will initialize them:

```
Employee(const char *nam,int num)
{
    initName(nam);
    idNumber = num;
    //strcpy(department,"");
    //strcpy(position,"");
    initDepartment("");
    initPosition("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer worked. Is it because i didn't allocate memory for the ptrs that strcpy did not work in this case?

Comment: @davis Yes, `department` does not have a value to begin with so it could be pointing anywhere. `initDepartment` uses `new` to allocate memory that `department` can then point to.